# Getting SocketTimeOut exception from server

Tags: android, asynchttpclient

I am uploading reports that having some fields and and option to upload one image in that report. Now these reports are stored in my local database. And now suppose I have stored 5 reports that having images. Now sometimes it's working fine. but sometime it is showing that error **SocketTimeOut exception** . Here is my code:-

```
private void sendData(JSONArray array) {

    String url = "www.example.com/api/daily-visit-report";

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("data", array);

    String[] images = new String[0];
    images = dbHelper.get_all_visit_images();

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

        try {
            params.put("" + i, new File(images[i]));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    client.setTimeout(120 * 1000);

    client.post(url, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {


            Log.d("Progress Data", "uploaded data => " + bytesWritten + " out of" + totalSize);

            long progressPercentage = (long) 100 * bytesWritten / totalSize;

            dialog.setProgress((int) progressPercentage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            if (responseString.equals("Data saved successfully")) {

                dbHelper.delete_visit_report();
                finish();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043573/fix-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out

Comment: @Ankita I am not using HttpClient.. I am using AsyncHttpClient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223286/getting-sockettimeoutexceptions-using-loopj-asynchttpclient-is-there-a-timeou

Comment: @Ankita I already used this